# NeoVim: vimspector unavailable: Requires Vim compiled with +python3

Tags: neovim, vim-plugin, vimspector

After installing vimspector with Plug.vim, when I reopen neovim, I met the problem as described in the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pip3 install neovim` fix this problem

Answer (score 5):

The python package `neovim` has been renamed to `pynvim` since version [`0.3.1`](https://github.com/neovim/pynvim/releases/tag/0.3.1), update the command to `pip3 install pynvim`